# How can you return 405 in flask_restful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask-restful

I am trying to build a login API using flask_resful. Everything works fine until I try to test with a method that is not defined. In this case the GET method. The API returns 404 Not Found - which is legit because the GET method was not specified.

What I want to do is to make it return 405 Method Not Allowed when a method was not defined.
I have been looking over the documentation and couldn't find a way to do it. Can someone help with this?

```
class Endpoint(Resource):
    def post(self):
        //do something
api.add_resource(Endpoint, '/static/v1/endpoint1')
```

Comment: import abort from flask module, and write abort(405), actually you can use whatever you want and you can specify the message you want to return

Comment: Similar generic solutions mentioned in the documentation [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators) will help you.